# Bootstrap viewport/columns mangle tooltips

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

It seems as though angular-ui tooltips are easily mangled when used in conjunction with bootstrap's grid. Here is a plunker illustrating the behavior:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gVekao4JCdC5O91RCoiW?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="tooltip_app">
  <head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('tooltip_app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    </script>
  </head>
<body>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class='container'>

<!--Row 1 - bad tooltip -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">2 <span tooltip="This is a real long tooltip designed to show you how tooltips have funny behaivior depending on bootstrap column width">bad</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">8</div>
</div>

<hr>

<!--Row 2 - good tooltip -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">8 <span tooltip="This is a real long tooltip designed to show you how tooltips have funny behaivior depending on bootstrap column width">good</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
</div>

<hr>

<!--Row 3 - egregious tooltip -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">9
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">2 (nested)
        <span tooltip="This is a real long tooltip designed to show you how tooltips have funny behaivior depending on bootstrap column width">worst</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">10 (nested)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
</div>

</div> <!--End Container-->

</body>
</html>
```

Notice how, when the viewport is small, everything works ok, but as you make the viewport more and more wide the tooltips start becoming compressed and misaligned. Is this behavior expected? If so, how can I ensure my tooltips stay aligned with the things they are supposed to be pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same thing happen to me. I would encourage you to double check the bootstrapped portions of your controllers and your CSS for code that is attempting to to align the same elements. By default, these data displaying grids will align things pretty well. Usually bootstrap allows you to place some layout configuration within your controller, AND because we are creatures of habit we will do the same in our CSS. Try to define as much of the layout of the grid as you can within the controller. I checked the documentation and followed the alignment rules to the t, assigning how I wanted everything to look to a variable, $scope.MyDefs and concentrated on definitions within the ui-grid portion of my controller, I could shrink and grow my screen and everything would stay in place. It was a really easy fix that drove me nuts for days on end.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use ui-grid as an alternative to bootstrap's layout classes (row, md-col)? Is ui-grid for page layout or for data tables?

Comment: My only thought would be that maybe the same problem is happening. NG-Grid and UI-Grid use bootstrap. Here's some documentation if you are interested.  http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/